# Single quotes are added to start and end of JSON

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-core

Single quotes are added to start and end of [this JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68v9r.png), after returning it to view as [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aswdj.png).

I tried removing the first and last character with JavaScript's `substring()` method to parse it with `JSON.parse()`, but it couldn't be removed.

What's the correct way to parsing it?

For those who wants the JSON;

```
"[{\"ParameterType\":\"Parametre Türü1\",\"DisplayType\":\"ComboBox\",\"Parameters\":[{\"Name\":\"Parametre1\",\"Ids\":[\"9786057751744\",\"9786257069335\",\"9786057580399\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\"]},{\"Name\":\"Parametre2\",\"Ids\":[\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"9789751969194\",\"0\"]}]},{\"ParameterType\":\"Parametre Türü2\",\"DisplayType\":\"CheckBox\",\"Parameters\":[{\"Name\":\"Param1\",\"Ids\":[\"9786057751744\",\"9786257069335\",\"9786057580399\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\"]},{\"Name\":\"Param2\",\"Ids\":[\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\",\"9789751969194\",\"0\"]}]},{\"ParameterType\":\"Parametre Türü3\",\"DisplayType\":\"ComboBox\",\"Parameters\":[{\"Name\":\"1\",\"Ids\":[\"9786057751744\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\"]},{\"Name\":\"2\",\"Ids\":[\"9786257069335\",\"0\",\"0\",\"9789751969194\"]},{\"Name\":\"3\",\"Ids\":[\"9786057580399\",\"0\",\"0\",\"0\"]}]}]"
```

Comment: Your JSON format is incorrect. check it with online formatter.

Comment: Could you share the code you are using and the output you are getting (and what you expect)? It seems to me that if you put that JSON through JSON.parse(<that_json>) the output is fine.

Comment: @DivyanshuSah that is shown here is valid JSON. It is a single string, and when parsed it returns another JSON encoded string.

Comment: @ArturoMendes. His JSON format are not correct. Look carefully. Key-value pair looks like this: `\"ParameterType\":\"Parametre Türü1\"`.

Comment: @DivyanshuSah I think you wanted to tag me. Yes, it is `\"ParameterType\":\"Parametre Türü1\"` but what is the problem about that. `"a string"` is JSON, it is a string encoded as `JSON` data. So what the OP shows is a single string encoded with JSON.

Comment: @DivyanshuSah I took the string, parsed it as a JSON and it looks like a normal object would. That's why I asked OP to be more specific about what he was expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON encoded data does not need to be an array, object, it could also be a single string:

```js
console.log(JSON.parse("\"test\""))
```

And that's what you got. It is a single string. That this string by itself also contains JSON encoded data indicates that the data is encoded twice.

If you do `JSON.parse(JSON.parse(data))` you will get the object.
But instead of parsing the data twice, you should find the reason why it was encoded twice and fix that.

This snippet shows what happens if you encode the data twice, and it looks like the data you have shown:

```js
let data = [{"ParameterType":"Parametre Türü1"}]

let encodedOnce = JSON.stringify(data)
let encodedTwice = JSON.stringify(encodedOnce)

console.dir(encodedTwice)

let decodedOnce = JSON.parse(encodedTwice)
let decodedTwice = JSON.parse(decodedOnce)

console.dir(decodedTwice)
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try with [JSONStringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.